# Python: How to Classify Unlabeled Images and Save into Class Folders?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, tensorflow

I have trained a CNN, and am trying to predict new unseen (unlabeled) images from a folder. I'm trying to predict them into 2 classes (Positive, Negative) using below:

```py
test_dir = '/path/to/test-set'
test_imgs = ['/path/to/test-set/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(test_dir)]

def read_and_process_image(list_of_images):

    X = []

    for image in list_of_images:
        X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))

    return X


X_test = read_and_process_image(test_imgs[0:10])
x = np.array(X_test)
test_datagent = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

I can't figure out how to save all the predicted images in a loop into related class folders ('neg' or 'pos'). Also, when I plot them, I see the color blue is more appearing in the predicted images and I'm not sure if they would be saved in blueish format.

```py
class_names = ['neg','pos']
i = 0
text_labels = []
plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
for batch in test_datagent.flow(x, batch_size=1):
    pred = new_model.predict(batch)
    for j in range(len(batch)):
        plt.imsave("/path/to/save-folder/ {}.jpg",batch[0])
        plt.subplot(5 / 5 + 1, 5, i+1)
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(pred[j])])
        imgplot = plt.imshow(batch[0])
        i +=1
        if i % 10 == 0:
             break
plt.show()
```

I really don't know how to proceed from this point, and any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Could it be because you're only including 10 data points in your test set: `X_test = read_and_process_image(test_imgs[0:10])`?

Comment: Also, the blue is because OpenCV opens images in BGR format whereas matplotlib opens them in RGB format. [See link](https://www.scivision.dev/numpy-image-bgr-to-rgb/)

Comment: @CoconutFred This is part of my question. I put 10 to test how it goes, which it fails. I need to include all the images. I edited the question tho

Comment: @CoconutFred So are they gonna be saved in bluish format if I used OpenCV? How can I change it to RGB format?